# Python Regex for strings that have a white space at the end in double quotes

Tags: json, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find all strings that have a white space at the end.

So for example **'a ',  'back-to-school ','dinner of ','grilled lamb '**
but not **'Jeffrey.'** and **'Arch': 'Architecture & Design'** those are strings that I would like to ignore.

I have tried this

```
p = re.compile('\"[a-zA-Z]+ \w[^,]\"')
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  Is there something missing in this regex?

`'D0': 'Ina prepares '
                         'a '
                       'back-to-school '
                         'dinner of '
                           'grilled lamb '
                              'chops for '
                              'Jeffrey.',
                                               'Distrme': 'Food '
                                                                          'Network',
                                               'Epis': 2,
                                               'Arch': 'Architecture & Design',`

Comment: How about `.*\w$`?

Comment: I have tried that as well.  That does not work. p = re.compile('.*\w$')

Comment: Try `re.compile(r'.*\w$')` instead

Comment: Are you using `\w` to match whitespace? I believe that matches alphanumeric and underscore. Maybe you meant to use `\s`?

Comment: still not finding any results: `p = re.compile(r'.*\w$') res = p.findall(line)`

Comment: Maybe `p = re.compile(r"'([^\s']+ +\w+ )'")` - see https://regex101.com/r/JWDEGx/1. But what is `line`? Do you have it as `for line in file`? Try `with open(fpath, "r") as f: p.findall(f.read())`

Comment: A string ends with a whitespace if it matches `/\s\z/`. Is that not what you want? Your title suggests you wish to match `abc" "'`, but that is inconsistent with your examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching based off of the end of the string. For instance, `re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+\s\Z')` will find instances ending with a whitespace character after alphanumeric characters.

I reference the following [cheat sheet](https://www.dataquest.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/python-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet.pdf) since there is plenty of options for building a regex.

Comment: Thanks I removed the \Z because it was not showing any results.  But after it is including what I also want to exclude.

Comment: Another thing would be to exclude any results that has a string after the white space

Comment: Honestly I would take a different approach to this problem than regexs since all you care about is finding whitespace at the end of a string. I'd call the final index position and do a simple if statement. So if you have a string called `p = 'grilled lamb '` do `if p[-1] == ' '` @greenee

Answer (score 0):

Try using positive lookahead:

```
[a-zA-Z -]+(?=\s$)
```

[Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/5iSq6i/2)

Regex explanation:

```
[a-zA-Z -]+       Match this set of chars - restrict as needed for your case
(?=\s$)           Positive lookahead - match only if string end on a space
```